# ScrollView not works on Relative Layout

Tags: android

I am trying to make my layout Scrollable by adding ScrollView as an parent for my Relative Layout.But my layout not scrolled.I have added the fillport property to true.

Here is my xml file:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"

            >

    <RelativeLayout 

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/repActivityTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:ellipsize="middle"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:text="@string/representativeTitle" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/repStreet"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/repImage"
            android:layout_marginTop="14sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/repImage"
            android:layout_margin="3sp"
            android:text="@string/repStreet" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/repState"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/repStreet"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/repImage"
            android:text="@string/repState" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/repCountry"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/repState"
            android:layout_below="@+id/repState"
            android:text="@string/repCountry" />

        <com.google.android.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/repMap"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="100dip"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/repImage"
            android:apiKey="0lsQmtr2D241pSL53j0vQ2lYUs4_ZIWkIHyHAKw" >
        </com.google.android.maps.MapView>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/firstHorizontalLine"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/repMap"
            android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/issues2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/issues1"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/issues2" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/secondHorizontalLine"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/accomplishments"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/issues"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/firstHorizontalLine"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/repStreet"
            android:text="@string/issues" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/accomplish2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/accomplish1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/accomplish1"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:text="@string/accomplishments2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/promises"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/issues"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@+id/accomplish2"
            android:text="@string/promises" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/thirdHorizontalLine"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/promises" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/accomplishments"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/issues2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/repMap"
            android:text="@string/accomplishments" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/accomplish1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/secondHorizontalLine"
            android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
            android:text="@string/accomplishments1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/issues1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/issues2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
            android:text="@string/issues1" />




        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/repImage"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="100dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/repActivityTitle"
            android:contentDescription="@string/representativeImage"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/promise1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/thirdHorizontalLine"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:text="@string/promises1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/promise2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/promise1"
            android:text="@string/promises2" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Here I have used the ScrollView but the full content of layout is not as showing.As scrolls not work here.

Comment: Hey Selvin both fill_parent and match_parent are same thing. Please suggest me the solution of it.

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove this line and check

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

And also you can try height of relativelayout to match_parent instead of wrap_content

```
    <RelativeLayout 

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    >
```

Comment: `match_parent` for height makes no sense in a vertical `ScrollView`.

Comment: Hey Nirali I have tried it but my layout gets weird after I try this.Please suggest me an solution for it.

Comment: I have set layout_height to wrap_content for ScrollView but its not work for me

Comment: yes when I have set the layout_height of ScrollView to wrap_content then it's works's for me